# Error attempting to get var names for namespace in cljunit

Tags: java, clojure

I'm working with a project that contains Java classes and Clojure files. The objective is to test Clojure files using java.

I'm using Cljunit for this purpose: https://github.com/mikera/cljunit

The code I use is next:

```
public class DemoClojureTest extends ClojureTest {
@Override
                public List<String> namespaces() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused") ArrayList<String> ns=new ArrayList<String>();
                    ns.add("com.example.demo.helloWorld");
                    return ns;
                }

    }
```

And the clojure file (helloWorld.clj) is:

```
(ns com.example.demo.helloWorld
  (:use clojure.test))

(deftest test1
  (is (= 1 3)))

(deftest test2
  (is (= 2 2)))
```

When I try to execute the DemoClojureTest I get this error:

Error attempting to get var names for namespace [com.example.demo.helloWorld]

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate com/example/demo/helloWorld__init.class or com/example/demo/helloWorld.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:432)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5298)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at mikera.cljunit.core$get_test_var_names.invoke(core.clj:67)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at mikera.cljunit.Clojure.getTestVars(Clojure.java:29)
    at mikera.cljunit.NamespaceTester.<init>(NamespaceTester.java:19)
    at mikera.cljunit.ClojureTester.<init>(ClojureTester.java:21)
    at mikera.cljunit.ClojureRunner.<init>(ClojureRunner.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:44)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a Java project or are you using La Clojure?

Comment: @Jared314 La Clojure plugin is installed in the IDE (IntelliJ) but I don't know if this project is using this.

Comment: This sounds like an Intellij specific classpath issue. Is the clojure source folder set as a "sources" folder?

Comment: @Jared314 Yes. It was a IntelliJ classpath issue. Marking the folder that contains the clj files as a "Test Source Folder", solve this problem. If you want to write your comment as a answer, I would accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, it looks like the IntelliJ test runner is either running your tests with a classpath that does not include your Clojure source files, or not including them in the build.

Make sure the folder, your Clojure files are in, is under a "Content Root" and marked as a "Sources", or "Test Sources", folder in the module settings.